# How to keep month in Descending order in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following Df in R.

DF<-

```
Month      Count     Group
Dec-20     12        A2
Feb-21     30        R5
Mar-21     43        R5
Jan-21     90        B1 
Total      175       -
```

The `Month` are jumbled in the above dataframe, I need to make them in Descending order.

Required Df<-

```
Month      Count     Group
Mar-21     43        R5
Feb-21     30        R5
Jan-21     90        B1
Dec-20     12        A2 
Total      175       -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zoo::as.yearmon` to convert the character values of `month` to `yearmon` class which can be arranged.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(desc(zoo::as.yearmon(Month, '%b-%y')))

#   Month Count Group
#1 Mar-21    43    R5
#2 Feb-21    30    R5
#3 Jan-21    90    B1
#4 Dec-20    12    A2
#5  Total   175     -
```

---

In base R, create a date object and then use `order`.

```
df[order(as.Date(paste0(df$Month, '-1'), '%b-%y-%d'), decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Month = c("Dec-20", "Feb-21", "Mar-21", "Jan-21", 
"Total"), Count = c(12L, 30L, 43L, 90L, 175L), Group = c("A2", 
"R5", "R5", "B1", "-")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I had missed to add `Total` row that will remain as is.

Comment: @user9211845 Both the answer work with `Total` row as well.